# Objective-C ReactiveCocoa fold (aggregate)

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have next code

```
RACSubject *subject = [RACSubject subject];

[subject subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"A: %@", x);
}];

[[subject aggregateWithStart:@"" reduce:^id(NSString *running, NSString *next) {
    return [running stringByAppendingString:next];
}] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"B: %@", x);
}];

[subject sendNext:@"hello"];
[subject sendNext:@"world"];
```

but

```
subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog(@"B: %@", x);
}
```

don't call, why?
and how to fix it?

current log:

```
2016-01-05 02:11:39.472 xxx[38643:7565618] A: hello
2016-01-05 02:11:39.472 xxx[38643:7565618] A: world
```

waiting log:

```
A: hello
A: world
B: hello world
```

p.s. ReactiveCocoa 2.5

Comment: Well, why would you expect to be called?

Comment: Why subscribeNext don't call? I see code RAC but i don't understand what I need do.

Comment: Then please update your question to reflect what you just said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for `aggregateWithStart:reduce:`

> Returns a signal that will send the aggregated value when the receiver completes, then itself complete.

The key is that *the receiver needs to complete* in order for the aggregate to "finish" and send its value along. So you need a `[subject sendCompleted];` statement.

If this isn't the behavior you want, there's a related method called `combinePreviousWithStart:reduce:` that will give you output like this:

```
A: hello
B: hello
A: world
B: helloworld
```